# Работа с датами в PHP

Tags: php, mysql

У меня такая проблема, необходимо сравнить дату с датой из MySQL datetime и текущей датой. Как реализовать – не знаю.

Есть вот такой код

```
$dateban = (mysqli_query($link, "SELECT chatBAN FROM tz_members WHERE usr='$name'"));
$tyday = strtotime('today');
echo '$dateban';
if ($dateban > $tyday) {}
else {
    throw new Exception('Вы заблокированны до $dateban');
}

if($row['usr']){}
else {
    throw new Exception('Неверный логин или пароль!');
}

if(!$name || !$email ){
    throw new Exception('Заполните все необходимые поля.');
}
```

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

```
$stm = mysqli_prepare($link, "SELECT chatBAN FROM tz_members WHERE usr=?");
$stm->bind_param("s", $name);
$stm->execute();
$stm->bind_result($dateBan);
$stm->fetch();
$stm->close();

if ($dateBan && strtotime($dateBan) < time()) {
    throw new Exception('Вы заблокированны до $dateban');
}
```

**P.S Не пользуйтесь в БД camelCase наименованием колонок и никогда не используйте прямую вставку параметров в строку при запросе!**

Comment: Не работает ваш код

Comment: @TomasRedl еще раз, ошибочка вышла :)

Comment: Сейчас условие не проходит(((

Comment: @TomasRedl Да, сначала сделал без привязки параметров, а потом быстро исправил на bind, убрал row, попробуйте еще раз :)

Comment: Всё работает!!! Уря!!!

Comment: А почему нельзя переменять прямые вставки?

Comment: @TomasRedl Возможна SQL-инъекция

Comment: @TomasRedl потому, что вы не знаете, что содержится в `$name`. Может там `';DELETE FROM tz_members WHERE NOT usr='`. Ну это в худшем случае. Да и в целом, с bind работать гораздо удобнее и приятнее, надо только начать.